# UWP broadFileSystemAccess using System.IO to read and extract rar files

Tags: c#, uwp, read-write, file-access

I am targeting build 17134 and trying to use system.IO to get the files in a directory. I'm also using sharpcompress to extract .rar files. From my understanding/what I've read online the new restricted capability "broadFileSystemAccess" should allow my app full access to any directory. My code is below and ATM I pass in a hard coded directory on my E drive.

```
    public void DirSearch(string sDir)
    {
        var ext = new List<string> { "*.rar", "*.zip" };

        foreach (String fileExtension in ext)
        {
            foreach (String file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sDir, fileExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                var archive = ArchiveFactory.Open(file);
                foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    if (!entry.IsDirectory)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(entry.Key);
                        entry.WriteToDirectory(@"E:\temp\", new ExtractionOptions() { ExtractFullPath = true, Overwrite = true });
                    }
                }

                Debug.WriteLine(file);
            }
        }
    }
```

This does not seem to work for me as I'm always getting:

`System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'E:\rars' is denied.'`

I've also tried using the folder picker + storageFile which does list the rar files but then the following line throws an UnauthorizedAccessException error:

```
var archive = ArchiveFactory.Open(file);
```

How can I read and write to my E drive using System.IO and Sharpcompress using the broadFileSystemAccess capability? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

As the introduction in the document [broadFileSystemAccess capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capabilities) and [Accessing additional locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations),

> This capability works for APIs in the [Windows.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage) namespace.

So you still can not get the file directly by the file's path like `E:\` using the sharpcompress Apis. But you can use the `StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync` Api to get the folder then use the `ArchiveFactory.Open(Stream stream, ReaderOptions readerOptions = null)` method to exact the file.

Here are some example code, you can put it as a reference.

```
public async void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    var ext = new List<string> { ".rar", ".zip" };
    var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(sDir);
    var exactFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("newFile", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
    using (var writeStream = await exactFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        foreach (var file in await folder.GetFilesAsync())
        {
            if (ext.Contains(file.FileType))
            {
                var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
                var archive = ArchiveFactory.Open(stream.AsStream());
                foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    if (!entry.IsDirectory)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(entry.Key);
                        entry.WriteTo(writeStream);
                    }
                }
                Debug.WriteLine(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---**Update**---

Since UWP app have file access permission, you can not use none [Windows.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage) namespace api to access the file path like `E:\foldre\` directly, but your app have the full permission to the local folder, you can use `IArchiveEntry.WriteToDirectory(string destinationDirectory)` method to exact the files to the local folder, then you can copy the files to the folder location you want, try the following code,

```
public async void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    var ext = new List<string> { ".rar", ".zip" };
    var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(sDir);
    var ExactLocalFolder =await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("ExactLocalFolder");
    foreach (var file in await folder.GetFilesAsync())
    {
        if (ext.Contains(file.FileType))
        {
            var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
            var archive = ArchiveFactory.Open(stream.AsStream());
            foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
            {
                if (!entry.IsDirectory)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(entry.Key);
                    //extract the files to local folder
                    entry.WriteToDirectory(ExactLocalFolder.Path);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //copy the files to the folder that you want to save the extract file into
    foreach (var file in await ExactLocalFolder.GetFilesAsync())
    {
        await file.CopyAsync(folder);
    }
    //delete the folder in the local folder
    await ExactLocalFolder.DeleteAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, got it to work with simple .zip files but not multi-part .rar files. It seams the stream only reads the initial .rar file and none of the additional parts

Comment: @SteveFitzsimons I have added the **Update** part in my answer, please check it.